# glOrtho in a 3D scene isn't working

Tags: opengl

I made a 3D scene and I used glOrtho and gluOrtho2D to get things to stay on my screen when I move the camera to look around in my 3D scene. But when I start to look around the characters disappear.
How do you get the characters to stay on your screen.

Comment: Can you post a short sample of your code? There are a number of places where things can go wrong.

Comment: ------------------------------------------------------>"No camera!"
OpenGL not OpenGL|ES.

Answer (score 0):

The projection matrix kind of defines your lens. But no matter what lens you use, if you turn the scene or move the camera, the view will change.

> How do you get the characters to stay on your screen.

Well, by keeping the "camera" in place.

OpenGL actually doesn't have a *camera*. It doesn't even have a scene. The only thing it sees are points, lines and triangles it draws one after another to the screen. What OpenGL has are transformation matrices. And in your case, all you have to do is set a projection and modelview, that will draw the characters at the desired place on the screen. And since OpenGL does not maintain a scene, you can change the transformation matrices anytime you want.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot a "glLoadIdentity();" somewhere...

After your calls to glOrtho...

```
glOrtho(0.0, windowWidth, 0.0, windowHeight, -10.0, 10.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Hope this helps.

-kropcke